# Google +1 button as a link?

Tags: css, button, hyperlink, social-networking

Can you have the Google +1 button as a simple link?

Like

```
<a href="http://google.com/+1/url=http://mysite.com" class="google-plus1">
  + 1
</a>
```

i don't like iframes

Comment: Check out these solutions: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157411/adding-a-google-plus-one-or-share-link-to-an-email-newsletter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid iframes, you may use this:
[+1 your website](https://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html)

Code for +1'ing *http://www.example.com*:

```html
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone href="http://www.example.com"></g:plusone>
```

Comment: I'd prefer a solution that does not require *loading any data from google* before the user has clicked the button. Kind of a "Go here to +1 my website" link. There are **privacy reasons** to not embed the pulsone API like this. It may even be illegal in some jurisdictions.