# Adding a Google Plus (one or share) link to an email newsletter

Tags: email, share, newsletter, google-plus, google-plus-one

I am trying to find a way to embed a share/+1 link for Google+ in a Newsletter, much like the Facebook share and tweeter tweet links can be embedded in a newsletter, which can be achieved with the following two urls:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[URL]&t=[TEXT]
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=sharethiscom&text=[TEXT]&url=[URL]
```

Is there a similar functionality available for Google Plus?

All I could find on my own, is the Google+ button, which unfortunately uses JavaScript and thus it cannot be used in an email newsletter. I would expect Google to provide a static url fallback, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: host a page with the javascript html and then call this static page.. what say ? .. why wait for google. ?

Comment: There are not absolutes, check out this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676658/share-link-on-google/8070581#8070581

Comment: pattermeister's answer provides a way to share on google+ using a URL with parameters. It worked for me.

Comment: pinterest link http://ajtroxell.com/articles/pinterest-and-google-plus-share-links-without-javascript/

Answer (score 212, accepted):

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

You can share the link on Google+ with the official [Google+ share link](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink).
Replace the `url` parameter with the URL encoded link you want to share.

Comment: yeah its nice and also working for me, But i need to add the title with this url, I tried and the query string like "&title-mytext" like that, But it does not affect with the share comments, what i do for this?... can u advice me!

Comment: @Matt I've been using this method for some time, but are you or anyone for that matter aware of method to pass just text and not a URL? I want to share a text string and not a URL similar to a tweet button.

Comment: What about for supplying a title/caption via the query string?  I'm trying to share a JPG and can't specify the HTML meta.

Comment: @Sangdol I found a mention of the share link quite a long way down on the official page... https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/ Seems only URL is supported.

Answer (score 36):

This one works fine for me :

`https://plus.google.com/share?url=your-page-url`

Comment: more solutions seem to be popping up. Google is finally getting their game straight

Answer (score 24):

The [share link](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink) allows you to do this. It will work in an email, but it's not quite the same as the +1 button.

To use the share link, add a link element to your email that complies with the [Google+ Buttons policy](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html). Set the href attribute to `https://plus.google.com/share?url={url encoded share target}`

For example, linking to https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com will allow you to [share example.com on Google+: [image: Google+ share button]](https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com) (yes, that is a working demo).

Check out the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink) for more info.

If you use this approach please be aware of the fact that it is not a direct replacement for the +1 button. The link shares the target URL on Google+, but it does not actually +1 the target page. Only the +1 button can +1 a page.

Answer (score 16):

Solution for those who needs **custom title, description and image**. You should make following changes to target URL:

**Step1.** add *itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"* into `<html>` tag. It will look like `<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">`. More itemtypes [here](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html)

**Step2.** Place the follwing meta tags into `<head>`, change *content* attributes according your needs:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="{Custom title goes here}">
<meta itemprop="description" content="{Custom description goes here}">
<meta itemprop="image" content="{http://www.your_url.com/your_image.png}">
```

**Step3.** Add the following link to your newsletter or anywhere you want:

```
<a href="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=http://www.your_url.com">Share it</a>
```

**Tip.** To check how google sees your page, you can use this tool http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets. Probably you'll be interested in section *Extracted rich snippet data from the page*

Good luck, Lauris

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the following.. :)

```
https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=[TEXT]%20[URL]
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally suggest Google Plus Interactive Posts button 
https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive 
to use in your apps/websites.Here Google Plus allows many customizations to do according to the requirement. I have used it in my app. Its a better option than Share button.

Comment: Can Interactive posts be used without JS? The scope of this question is Newsletter or other no-js scenarios

Comment: @Dogoku Yes Interactive Post can be used without JS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps. It works (partially) for me.
http://www.stateofsearch.com/share-on-google-plus-any-website/

Answer (score 0):

There has got to be a way to do this by hacking the +1 script.

If you are interested in just changing the apperance you should download and modify [this](https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/Publisher/sprite.png) to suit your requirements.

Then, add this to your css:

```
.Uu .KF {
    background: url("your-replacement-image") no-repeat scroll -132px -21px transparent !important;
}
```

to override the Google icons. However, this is probably very unstable and subject to change.