# Customise the image a Google+ Share button displays upon sharing

Tags: google-plus, mailchimp

I have found this link:
[Adding a Google Plus (one or share) link to an email newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157411/adding-a-google-plus-one-or-share-link-to-an-email-newsletter)

It's great, it helped me to make a Google+ button for my HTML Email campaign.  I'm using Mailchimp and I edited it as such:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=*|RSSITEM:URL|*">
<img src="http://mywebsite.co.uk/images/googleplus.jpg">
</a>
```

So now it has a customised image, and also works in my RSS email campaign.  Mailchimp support didn't know this was possible, so that made me happy.

HOWEVER, what I want to achieve is to be able to choose which image is shared by default when the user clicks.  Does anyone know if that's possible?

I hope my solution helps someone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image that is displayed in the share is determined by the Schema.org markup on the page that you are sharing. Specifically, you will want to set the `itemprop="image"` to point to the image you wish to share.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

It is important to note that this is the markup for your page, so the same image that appears in the share is the one that will represent your page in other snippet tools.

You can see how this works, and see additional markup options, at https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/.

Answer (score 0):

the sharer uses this image as the default one, but displays other images as well (they can be selected with the arrows on hover). Is there a way to disable the other images, for navigation images etc.?